# Does having category name in permalinks affect SEO when having a post in multiple categories?

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks, urls

If I change the permalink structure to the following in the Permalinks settings page in WordPress:

`www.example.com/%category%/%postname%/`

Then I create a post with the slug `my-post` and add two categories for that post `category1` and `category2`, will Google see this as duplicate content because if you go to both these links:

`www.example.com/category1/my-post/`

`www.example.com/category2/my-post/`

They will go to the same post but the URL does not change, isn't this classed as duplicate content? Will Google and other search engines penalise a site that uses this practice? What is the recommend approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not affect it because Wordpress redirects links to post leaving you with only one canonical and working one. Post would be visible in both categories but will have only one correct permalink.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I forgot about that meta tag. Thanks!